# how i create filter on birthday-date? for example ( last 7 day, last 90 day )

Tags: angular, angular7

=> this is my json data.

```js
newUser = [
    {"id":1,"name":"viky","birthDate":"18/06/2019"},
    {"id":2,"name":"chetan","birthDate":"3/07/2019"},
    {"id":3,"name":"khushi","birthDate":"11/12/2019"},
    {"id":4,"name":"nency","birthDate":"19/04/2019"},
    {"id":5,"name":"urmil","birthDate":"27/03/2019"},
    ];
```

when i click on  ( last 7 day ) option then display user which birthday in last 7 days.

Comment: what code do you laready have? please provide more code.

Comment: generally, create a pipe with angular CLI, `ng g p <path/pipe-name>`. Put your filtering logic in there. I recommend using `momentJS` for calculations with dates, but you can also do it without.

Comment: when user select option in days get the date before that day like if user has selected last 7 days then get the date ago and get the data between today and 7 day's ago date using momentJS you can do this, but remember your date format should be same to compare.

Comment: @bhavesh, as your date is in format dd/MM/yyyy its good that you can create a new propertie  (must be a string) -using a forEach- with the date in format yyyyMMdd-, then only need filter as another string

Answer (score 1):

You can use diff method of moment library

```
newUser = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "viky", "birthDate": "18/06/2019" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "chetan", "birthDate": "3/07/2019" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "khushi", "birthDate": "11/12/2019" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "nency", "birthDate": "19/04/2019" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "urmil", "birthDate": "27/03/2019" },
  ];

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.newUser.filter(c => Math.abs((moment().diff(moment(c.birthDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'days'))) <= 7));
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxjhuo

Comment: thank you friend, it is really help full for me.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Vanilla JavaScript approach, if you do not feel like installing and managing external dependencies.

We convert both today's date, as well as the `birthDate` within the array into milliseconds. Then, we filter through the `newUser` array, and check if the inidividual dates are within the past 7 days.

```js
const newUser = [
  {id:1, name: 'viky', birthDate: '18/06/2019'},
  {id:2, name: 'chetan', birthDate: '3/07/2019'},
  {id:3, name: 'khushi', birthDate: '11/12/2019'},
  {id:4, name: 'nency', birthDate: '19/04/2019'},
  {id:5, name: 'urmil', birthDate: '27/03/2019'},
  {id:6, name: 'urmil2', birthDate:'19/06/2019'},
  {id:7, name: 'urmil3', birthDate:'15/06/2019'},
];

const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);

const res = newUser.filter(user => {
  dateSplit = user.birthDate.split('/');
  const birthDate = new Date(dateSplit[2], dateSplit[1] - 1, dateSplit[0]).getTime();
  const difference = (today - birthDate) / (1000*60*60*24);
  return difference <= 7 && difference >= 0;  
});
console.log(res);
```